# How to retrieve the data of the value entered in the text field

Tags: flutter, api, flutter-futurebuilder

I want it to show on the screen as soon as I enter the location, how can I do it?

i have to use ctrl + s when i try this way

```
  Future<void> getData() async{
   data = await client.getCurrentWeather(locatian.text.toString());
  }

  TextEditingController locatian = new TextEditingController();

        body: FutureBuilder(
          future: getData(),
          builder: (context, snapshot){
            if(snapshot.connectionState==ConnectionState.done){
              return Column(
                children: [
                  Padding(
                    padding: const EdgeInsets.all(9.0),
                    child: TextField(
                      controller: locatian,
                      decoration: InputDecoration(
                        border: OutlineInputBorder(),
                        hintText: "Sehir Giriniz",
                        prefixIcon: Icon(Icons.search),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                  GuncelVeri(Icons.wb_sunny_rounded, "${data?.derece}", "${data?.sehir}"),
                  bilgiler("${data?.humidity}","${data?.feels_like}", "${data?.pressure}"),],
              );
```

Answer (score 1):

you better to call the api in onChange function
to trigger text change and call API each time the text changed

Answer (score 1):

you should try the [onChanged](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/TextField/onChanged.html) property of TextField:

> Called when the user initiates a change to the TextField's value: when
> they have inserted or deleted text.
>
> This callback doesn't run when the TextField's text is changed
> programmatically, via the TextField's controller. Typically it isn't
> necessary to be notified of such changes, since they're initiated by
> the app itself.
>
> To be notified of all changes to the TextField's text, cursor, and
> selection, one can add a listener to its controller with
> TextEditingController.addListener.